# Change IMG SRC using Javascript, for one specific image

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple GreaseMonkey script.

I want to change the SRC of an IMG using GM as I cannot change the actual source in the code of the HTML itself.

This is the HTML snippet:

```
<img src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_LOGO.png" title="NEW_LOGO.png" border="0">
```

I could do something like:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i=0; i<imgs.length; i++)
{
 imgs[i].src="path_to_other_image/image.gif";
}
```

However, I only want to swap the IMG src for the image called NEW_LOGO.png, but I can't work out how to get the script to find that one single image. Unfortunately the HTML for the image doesn't reference the image via an ID or CSS class name so I can't narrow it down that way.

Tried this:

```
var imgs = document.querySelector('[src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_UNI_LOGO.png"]');
for (i=0; i<imgs.length; i++)
{
 imgs[i] = imgs[i].replace('/OA_MEDIA/NEW_UNI_LOGO.png','https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Is it a choice to not use js libraries like jQuery ? could be really simple with it jQuery('img[src="NEW_LOGO.png"]').attr('src','path_to_other_image/image.gif') ;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't have that option

Comment: @PierreGranger — Why bother with jQuery? querySelector does that already.

Comment: Didn't knew about it ;) querySelector is abled on every browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
document.querySelector('[src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_LOGO.png"]');
```

or

```
document.querySelector('[title="NEW_LOGO.png"]');
```

So basically

```
document.querySelector('[src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_LOGO.png"]').src = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have edited my question to include my best guess as using your method but it doesn't work - I wondered what I am missing (apart from intelligence!).

Comment: `document.querySelector` only returns one result. You need `document.querySelectorAll` if you want to iterate over all of them.

Comment: Thanks - that's fine, as there is only one image I want to change. But for some reason it's not picking up the change.

Comment: You need to do `document.querySelector('[src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_LOGO.png"]').src = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png';` and not just call `replace` on it. Then it should work

Comment: If I add a quick test into the script: alert(imgs[i]);, then the alert returns "[object HTMLImageElement]". Is that why the replace is not working - because there is nothing for it to replace?

Comment: As I said, you cannot just call `replace` on an `HTMLImageElement`. You need to change it's `src` attribute.